# Oracle SQL Check

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to implement an Oracle SQL database, in one of my tables I must introduce a restriction which does not allow to have more than 4 people in the same group:

I've tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (name VARCHAR (20) PRIMARY KEY, group VARCHAR (3), CHECK (COUNT (*) group FROM PERSON) <=4);
```

also this (among others):

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (name VARCHAR (20) PRIMARY KEY, group VARCHAR (3), CHECK NOT EXISTS (Select COUNT(*) FROM PERSON GROUP BY group HAVING COUNT(*) > 4);
```

But I'm getting errors every time (ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here or ORA-02251: subquery not allowed here.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: `group` is a keyword and reserved word in SQL.  Try using another column name.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues with this

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON (
    name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    group VARCHAR(3),
    CHECK (COUNT (*) group FROM PERSON) <=4);
);
```

1. Oracle explicitly prefers `VARCHAR2()` to `VARCHAR()`.
2. `GROUP` is a really bad name for a column, because it is a keyword.  Surely you can find something like `group_name` or whatever for the name.
3. `CHECK` constraints only work *within* a single row.

Probably the best way to handle this is:

- Create a new table called `groups` -- or whatever.  It should have a `group_id` as well as `group_name` and `num_persons`.
- Add triggers to `person` to keep the `counter` up-to-date for `insert`s, `delete`s, and `update`s to `person`.
- Add a check constraint to `groups`, say `check (num_persons <= 4)`.

Comment: `grouping` is also a keyword ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the table as following:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE PERSON (
>     name VARCHAR2(20) PRIMARY KEY,
>     group_ VARCHAR2(3) -- added _ after column name
> ); -- used varchar2 as data type of column
> ```

Then create before insert trigger as following:

> ```
> create trigger person_trg
> before insert on person
> for each row
> declare
> group_cnt number;
> begin
> select count(distinct name)
> into group_cnt
> from person
> where group_ = :new.group_;
>
> if group_cnt = 4 then 
> raise_application_error(-20001, 'more than 4 persons are not allowed in the group');
> end if;
>
> end;
> /
> ```

I have used `distinct` person name as more than 4 distinct persons are not allowed in the group as per your requirement.

[db<>fiddle demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59009879/oracle-sql-check)

Cheers!!

Comment: It won't work due to ORA-04091. And if it somehow does - there are a bunch of other issues with that approach.